# Who buried Zarabeth?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

In the *Star Trek: TOS* episode "All Our Yesterdays", guest actress Mariette Hartley plays Zarabeth, a woman who is exiled by being sent back in time alone to her planet's ice age.  When Spock and Dr. McCoy arrive via a time machine, she is grateful to finally have companionship.

At the end of the episode, after Spock and McCoy return to their own time, Spock states:

> SPOCK: Yes, it happened. But that was five thousand years ago. And she is dead now. Dead and **buried**. Long ago.

Considering that Zarabeth was now alone again, **who buried Zarabeth?**

Comment: I see no reason to conclude that anyone was responsible for her burial. Time and geology seem a sufficient explanation. No nameable entity buried the dinosaurs, and yet they seem to have ended up buried regardless.

Comment: "dead and buried" is a common-enough expression that the humans who wrote the episode and the human who said the line may well have done so without thinking about the fact that there was nobody to perform the burial.

Answer (score 1):

In the novel *Yesterday's Son* the funeral arrangements for her body would have been handled by her and Spock's son, Zar.

Comment: Normally we only consider primary sources, not the licensed works.  In this case you still appear to be incorrect, though, since according to Memory Beta, Zor merely preserved her body until it could be cremated.

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect that.